# Configure at boot on Android

Tags: android, boot

There is a property named `icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts` which usually starts with value `1`, this property is located at `/proc/sys/net/ipv4` and I need that starts with `0`. Change the value is really simple, I can do that with:

```
echo "0" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts
```

But I need this already configured at boot.

Comment: Is this for your personal device, for a custom ROM, or for an app you are trying to build?

Comment: Forgot to say, sorry.It is a Virtual Machine on a Virtual Box running Android 4.3, and I need this property with value 0 to not ignore broadcasts, so my Java application can send ICMP packages.

Comment: Is this an app you intend to distribute?

Comment: No, at least not in my mind for now. I am building a java aplication that receives request from mobiles and send the task to a virtual machine

Comment: How is this question related to programming?

Comment: Hi @DerGolem, I believe a shell script could do that, if it is configured at init.rc, I just don't know how to do, so I don't think I am wrong at posting my doubts. here. Thank you.

Comment: I think it's more a question about file system management, rather than a development question.